# android studio 3.2 - Dependency details view showing multiple modules, why?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.2

I just downloaded android studio 3.2. my project app module has a single dependency which i declare in settings.gradle like this:

```
include ':app', ':auth'
project(':auth').projectDir = new File('firebaseui-auth/auth')
```

notice the project has app, and auth as the two modules.  app depends on auth per this in my gradle file (in app):

```
implementation project(':auth')
```

but when i click on the new dependency detail view in android studio i see that it has two dependencies.  to get to the dependncy details you must open up build variants on the side bar:

[image]

then lick on the blue information bubble that you see and it will open the following:

[image]

Why is the app module pointing to 3 different auth modules ? i only have a single auth module and i showed you above in the app gradle file that i am dependent only on auth module.  Why 3 ?